# Reading non textual content and write it back to the file

Tags: java, character-encoding

I need to read the line     `<row>⠁⠇⠕⠝⠛⠀⠺⠊⠞⠓⠀⠍⠁⠞⠓⠑⠍⠁⠞⠊⠉⠁⠇⠀⠉⠕⠝⠞⠑⠝⠞</row>` from a file and then write back. But when I write back content in file is

```
<row>â ?â ƒâ •â §â ‘â €â ™â ‘â ?â •â žâ ‘â €â ?â €â Šâ ?â žâ ‘â —â ›â —â ?â žâ Šâ •â ?</row>
```

Can you please help me to fix it? I need to do this in java

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some sample code of what you're doing right now?

Comment: Those are [Braille Patterns](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Unicode/Braille_Patterns) and have their own block in unicode. They may not be ascii, but they are very much textual.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a text encoding issue. The problem may be happening either while reading or while writing, or while reading again what was written. Your output looks like misinterpreted little-endian UTF-16 (except for the tags that look like plain ASCII).

BTW your "non-textual" remark is just misleading -- any character data is textual, these are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a binary stream instead of a character stream.

In other words you are doing this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

But you **should** be doing this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: Those seem to be braille characters, so this has nothing to do with binary data.

Comment: ¿wouldn't my proposal of doing things in binary mode preserve the original content correctly when writing them back?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Now we've got the `<row>` part, it looks like it *is* meant to be text data after all. However, you've given us no information about what produced this file, or what the data between the `<row>` tags is meant to be. *Is* it text, or is it binary data and somehow you're meant to shift from reading the text of `<row>` to reading the binary data? How are you meant to know where the `<row>` ends?

*You've* got to understand the meaning and format of your data - we can't do that for you. If you can explain the meaning and format, we can help you turn that into code... but we can't help much without that information.

---

You talk about reading a "line" - but then you give non-text data. There's no such concept as a "line" within binary data.

If you're currently using a `Reader` of some description (e.g. `FileReader`) - **don't**. They're designed for text data. Trying to treat binary data as text is almost guaranteed to lose information.

Read with an `InputStream`, write with an `OutputStream`, and all should be well (assuming you use them correctly, of course - in particular, use the return value from `InputStream.read` appropriately).

Comment: The example looks like it is valid Unicode "text" -- a `Reader` would still work if the correct encoding is used.

Comment: Surely it's character data, in some character encoding (how else was it pasted in the question)?

Comment: @casablanca: When I originally read the question, it didn't have the `<row>` part, which is definitely more suggestive of text data.

Comment: @eggyal: Just because the OP is able to copy it *as if* it's text data doesn't mean it *is* text data. Open up a JPG in Notepad - you can still cut and paste, but it's not really text data.

Comment: Okay, fair point.  But it still looks like Braille character data to me.

Comment: @eggyal: It's hard to say, given that on my computer at least, the input in the question is all coming out as the same character repeated many times, but clearly it's not really - as the *output* is different. We need more information from the OP.